# How to embed a youtube video?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in a `QWebEngineView` widget, however, the video is not playing and I'm getting this msg:

"Video indisponible Watch on YouTube"

[image: 5d3760b4-00b8-4513-a9f3-7ebdd76e2a9f-image.png]

I tried with different videos and in all I got the same error, I also tried setting some settings up like:

```
    QWebEngineView* view = new QWebEngineView();
    view->setHtml(R"(<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TodEc77i4t4" title="Qt 6 - The Ultimate UX Development Platform" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>)");

    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FullScreenSupportEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::AllowRunningInsecureContent, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::SpatialNavigationEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);

    view->show();
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like they blocked you...

Comment: @PaulSanders blocked? who blocked? as i mentioned, i tested with different videos all i get the same result.

Comment: YouTube alias Google, presumably, might be something to do with your [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string (don't know how Qt handles that, but I imagine you can set it somehow).  Does it work in your browser?

Comment: @PaulSanders yes it does work in my browser, it also works if i set it as `view->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/TodEc77i4t4");`, but then i cant set the widget borders, frame etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't use **HTML** and I test this way and it shows me the Video:

I add this code in MainWindow:

```
    QWidget *wgt = new QWidget(this);
    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(wgt);

    wgt->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("border: 1px solid black;\n"
                                          "border-radius: 25px;background-color:black;"));
    ui->centralwidget->layout()->addWidget(wgt);


    QWebEngineView* view = new QWebEngineView(wgt);
    view->setWindowTitle("Qt 6 - The Ultimate UX Development Platform");

    view->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/TodEc77i4t4"));

    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FullScreenSupportEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::AllowRunningInsecureContent, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::SpatialNavigationEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);

    wgt->layout()->addWidget(view);
```

**This is the Result:**

[image]

For Style your widget please look at [Qt Style Sheets Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html), it's similar to CSS and you can use this.

for example, you can add this:

```
    view->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("border: 1px solid black;\n"
                                          "border-radius: 25px;"));
```

QWebEngineView object didn't get style so I add it inside the helper widget and add style to that.

you can clone it from here :

https://gitlab.com/ParisaHR/stackoverflow_qwebengineview

Comment: @Vitor yeah by stylesheet we usually set frame/borders and etc to our widgets.

Comment: @Vitor please look at my updated answer and if you need help ask me.

Comment: I tested `setStyleShtet` but the widget didnt get any border, i think `QWebEngineView` doesnt works with StyleSheet