# How to round the borders of a video element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, qt

I have a youtube video `embedded` into a **Qt widget,** is it possible to display it with rounded borders?

The red border in the picture below is just to illustrate what I'm trying to mean, how could I round the borders of the `video` instead of the borders around it?

```js
document.getElementById('player').style.border = "12px solid red";
document.getElementById('player').style.borderRadius = "12px";
```

[image]

While searching i found an example using [iframe](https://jsfiddle.net/6mr1tvjf/2/), I'm trying to get the video looking like it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed a youtube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74169933/how-to-embed-a-youtube-video)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

You can't customize an embedded video style directly, unless the provider, provides some relative options for the style.

##### But you can do some modifications with extra layers and CSS

In order to make the youtube video border rounded, you need to create a parent division for it with the `overflow: hidden;` property and custom `border-radius`, then to make it looks like a rounded element you need to change its position and put it in the top left or the right place to allow it fit the available box. To set it to the right place on the screen you have to specify the `width` and `height` of the `iframe` element respectively to fit it in your situation.

It should be something like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.video {
  border-radius: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe width="560" height="310" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tTw2-aHcUEA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Do it with JS only

As the OP requested I implement the answer in JS only to let them do workarounds in `Qt` widgets. It's simply done with JS built-in functions like: [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), and [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), which you can read more about how they function in their respective pages. This approach can be directly implemented in the browser dev tools console overview section.

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tTw2-aHcUEA")
iframe.setAttribute("width", "560");
iframe.setAttribute("height", "310");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

const video = document.createElement("div");
video.style.borderRadius = "2rem";
video.style.overflow = "hidden";
video.style.position = "absolute";
video.style.top = "0";
video.style.left = "0";
video.style.transform = "translateZ(0)";

video.appendChild(iframe);

const body = document.body;
body.appendChild(video);
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/SMAKSS/pen/bGKbjaE

Comment: Is it possible to 'replicate' your answer using just the Chrome Dev Tools Console? I mean, launch the embedded video in your browser, hit `F12`, and using the console round the borders of the video. I'm asking cause the way you answered I don't know how to adapt it to the `Qt` widget. Having all the code executed in the console I can easily replicate it into the `Qt` widget.